# Regular expression to match n times in which n is not fixed

Tags: regex

The pattern I want to match is a sequence of length n where n is right before the sequence.

For example, when the input is "1aaaaa", I want to match the single character "a", as the first number specifies only 1 character is matched.

Similar, when the input is "2aaaaa", I want to match the first two characters "aa", but not the rest, as the number 2 specifies two characters will be matched.

I understand `a{1}` and `a{2}` will match "a" one or two times. But how to match `a{n}` in which n is not fixed?

Is it possible to do this type of match using regular expressions?

Comment: What language/tool are you using?

Comment: You would have to dynamically generate the regex based on the first character. Regex alone can't do this.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen any language. If you have a solution in Perl, Python, Java, or Javascript, that'll be helpful. Just want to have a general idea.

Comment: If you have a small finite number of options, then you can potentially use the if clause on the regex to accomplish your goal. Otherwise, you will need to dynamically generate as 4castle suggests. [Example Regex](https://regex101.com/r/F1iPs1/1)

Comment: @Nathan thanks for the example. Unfortunately, I don't have finite number of options. Probably I will have to dynamically generate regular expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for repeating numbers.

```
import re

a="1aaa2bbbbb1cccccccc4dddddddddddd"

for b in re.findall(r'\d[a-z]+', a):
    print b[int(b[0])+1:int(b[0])+1+int(b[0])]
```

Output:

```
a
bb
c
dddd
```

Comment: Thanks. But my question is more complex than this.

Comment: @zhanxw  How about now?

Comment: in my case, a is one line. `a="1aaaaaa2bbbbbbbbbbb3cccccccccc4ddddddddddd"`. The location of the numbers are not fixed. Thanks for your codes though.

Comment: @zhanxw  How about now? Can numbers repeat? This won't work for that case, I'll try to improve it.

Comment: I just accepted your answer - it does solve my problem although not a powerful regular expression as what I originally expected. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Though I have done in Java, it will help you get going in your program.

Here you can select the **first** letter as **sub-string** from the given input string and use it in your regex to match the string accordingly.

```
public class DynamicRegex {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter a string: ");
        String str = scan.nextLine();

        String testStr = str.substring(0, 1);   //Get the first character from the string using sub-string.

        String pattern = "a{"+ testStr +"}";    //Use the sub-string in your regex as length of the string to match.

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);

        Matcher m = p.matcher(str);

        if(m.find()){
            System.out.println(m.group()); 
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: Thanks. But the number may not be the first character, and there can be different lengths (e.g. 1a, 2aa)

Actually, the input string can be more complex than what I stated in the question, e.g. input = "1a..2aa.....1aaa...". I want to match the "1a", "2aa" and "1a". 
That's why I am looking for a regular expression that can match all of them.